# Kivy Python | Position TextInput

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to position my TextInput (i.e. the field) to the left of the but I cannot do this:
[image]

Comment: Please post your .kv code. You probably want the following: An outer BoxLayout(horizontal) which contains a TextInput and another BoxLayout(vertical) which contains your buttons.

Comment: did it now another problem i can't "take" the text input how do i do that? would be happy for an example code

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rearranging your gui in kv scrpit.

Replace

```
Label:
    ...
TextInput:
    ...
```

with

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'horizontal'
    Label:
        ...
    TextInput:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question with code sample and help link (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-textinput-in-kivy-using-kv-file/)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        title = "Sample Layout not using kv file"
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        self.textinput = TextInput(text="")
        self.textinput.bind(text=self.get_text)
        self.btn1 = Button(text='Move text to label')
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.get_text)
        self.btn2 = Button(text='World')
        self.lbl1 = Label(text="text goes here")
        layout.add_widget(self.textinput)
        layout.add_widget(self.btn1)
        layout.add_widget(self.btn2)
        layout.add_widget(self.lbl1)
        return layout  

    def get_text(self, *args):
        print(self.textinput.text)
        self.lbl1.text = "You wrote " + self.textinput.text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```